# Convert Working Day Data Frame into a Calendar Day data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I want to convert my daily working day stock price data frame into an everyday stock price data frame. The data on Saturday and Sunday should be that of Friday.
Thank You

Comment: Please provide some data with the code you have already tried. Then we will can help you. We don't guess your thoughts.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data ?